# Angularjs Input text appending number instead of adding it

Tags: angularjs, input, append

When user type in number then click on "+", it will **append** the count instead of perform addition for the counter.

But it is working fine when performing "-" or "+" action without key in number in the input box.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller ="myCtrl">
  <span ng-click="count = count + 1">+</span>
  <input type="text" ng-model="count" valid-number>
  <span ng-click="count = count - 1"  ng-show="count > 0">-</span>
</div>
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/shenglim/Lyugypqk/4/

Anybody can help out on this? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple example will work if uses ng-click="test()" and perform basic addition, if you need to retrieve from existing json which return string, Try to use parseInt() on the JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<input type="number">`.

The data type for `type="text"` makes it a string and `"1" + 1 = "11"`

JSFiddle ~ http://jsfiddle.net/Lyugypqk/2/

Comment: Hi Phil, 
The reason i put input type ="text" is to prevent user from input negative value by directive control. If type="number" user still able to input negative by click arrow down.

Comment: @Took then add `min="0"`.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't stated clearly in the question asked. I wanted to prevent negative and decimals from user.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can add two methods to increase and decrease the values into the controller and use them,

```
    $scope.increment = function(){
        $scope.count++;
    };

    $scope.decrement = function(){
        $scope.count--;
    };

    <span ng-click="increment()">+</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="count" valid-number>
    <span ng-click="decrement()" ng-show="count > 0">-</span>
```